# spring email scheduler sending out too many emails

Tags: java

I've attempted to send out an email using the spring scheduler so that it will send out an email twice a day at 9AM and 4PM, but the issue that I'm running into is that the scheduler will send out 4 emails instead of 1 when it executes the job. Here's what I have at the moment in my spring configuration file :

```
    <!-- Email Notification Job -->
<bean id="emailJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="name" value="emailNotification" />
    <property name="group" value="notification" />
    <property name="targetObject" ref="notificationService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="createNotification" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
    <!-- Email job description -->
<bean id="emailNotification" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 9,16 * * ?" />   <!-- Starts at 9am and 4pm everyday -->
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="emailJobDetail" />
</bean>
     <!-- Scheduler -->
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="emailNotification"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So this will execute the createNotification method in the spring service 'notificationService' which will send out the email to the user. Does anyone have a better understanding of this issue?

Comment: are you running in a cluster with 4 servers?..... web or standalone application? Have checked if you are entering 4 times the `createNotification` method or if it inside this method that you are looping 4 times?

Comment: i've checked and the createNotification method will only send out the email once, this is ran on jboss on my local server

Comment: Can you try to send a email from another email client and check still receive 4 emails if so there is no issue with your code.

Comment: what do you mean from another email client? i'm simply using Spring's simplemailmessage and javamailsenderimpl to send out the email

Comment: i mean gmail or yahoo .... etc

Comment: i only receive one email from another client

Comment: ok that means issue with your application. Can you just show the bit of codes.

Comment: Could you show us the code of your `notificationService` please. The spring configuration looks fine, the cron expression is valid, your mail server seems to works fine...